# How to display data from state in React?

Tags: reactjs

I was trying to create a structure in react having a datawith image and a option to select.

**If the option is selected then only submit button should display success alert.**

I have created a Json data which contain the details

here is code sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-paper-d62f8?file=/src/App.js

Here is what I expecting but my code is throwing error.

Here is what i have tried

```
    return (
        <div>
            <table>
                <tbody> 
                    {
                        Object.keys(state.Data).map(key => (
                            <tr>
                                <td>{state.Data[key].QUIZ}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>{state.Data[key].Images}</td>
                            </tr>
                            {
                                state.Data[key].options.map(option => (
                                    <div>
                                        <div>
                                            {option}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                ))
                            }
                            <button onClick = {showAlert}>{state.Data[key].buttonLabel}</button>
                        ))
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>

        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: just want to add further warning based on the accept solution, you might want to also enclose your `<div><div>option</div></div>` with <tr></tr> as well as the `<button>`. the direct child of `<tbody>` must be `<tr>`, you might want to check out html table structure. Otherwise you will face some other layout issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made some mistakes in return statement as well as in array methods.

Try the below code:

```
Object.keys(state.Data).map(key => 
    <>
        <tr>
            <td>{state.Data[key][0].QUIZ}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>{state.Data[key][0].Images}</td>
        </tr>
        {
            Object.keys(state.Data[key][0].options[0]).map(option => 
                <div>
                    <div>
                        {state.Data[key][0].options[0][option]}
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        }
        <button onClick = {showAlert}>{state.Data[key][0].buttonLabel}</button>
    </>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Added empty elements as prompted. There are other issues, but the issue you asked passed. I'm new to react as well.

```
               Object.keys(state.Data).map(key => (
              <>  
                <tr>
                    <td>{state.Data[key].QUIZ}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>{state.Data[key].Images}</td>
                </tr>
                {
                    state.Data[key].options.map(option => (
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                {option}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    ))
                }
                <button onClick = {showAlert}>{state.Data[key].buttonLabel}</button>
            </>    
            ))
```